# Struture "Student" C++

Tags: c++

I'm studying c++ and I need to create structure "Student" in c++ and work with it (I use Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express)
I created **Student.cpp** file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

const int num = 5;

struct Student  {
    char name[30];
    int groupNumber;
    int progress[num];
};
```

and It's my programm

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Student.cpp"
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

int n;
cout << "Введите количество студентов в группе n = ";
cin >> n;

Student * Group = new Student[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    cout << "Введите ФИО: ";
    cin >> Group[i].name;
    Group[i].groupNumber = rand()%5 + 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        Group[i].progress[j] = rand()%5 + 2;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        sum += Group[i].progress[j];
    }
    double count = (double)sum/5;
    if (count < 4) continue;
    cout << "\n\n" << Group[i].name << "\nГруппа: " << Group[i].groupNumber << "\nСредний бал: " << count;
}

cout << "\n\n";

delete [] Group;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

but when I tried to input name with spacebar (for example, firstname and lastname for one student), I got error like my circle missed one step
[image]

I tried to use `string` for name

```
string name
```

but the problem stays the same.

What's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Besides what everyone else already told you, you don't include .cpp files. Common declarations in  .hpp file (which is included), and the corresponding definitions in a  .cpp file (which is compiled).

Comment: @Matteo Italia Can you explain me about it? I have been studying c++ a couple of weeks only and it's difficult to understand what I should put in `.h` files and what in `.cpp` files.

Comment: @Heidel since you're new to C++ a simple rule to follow is: function declarations and `class`/`struct` definitions should go in `.h`/`.hpp` files, and function defintions should go in `.cpp` files. This model gets complicated a bit once you learn about `inline` functions, internal linkage, `template`s, etc.

Comment: As I understand, I need to put my structure `#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

const int num = 5;

struct Student  {
 wstring name;
 int groupNumber;
 int progress[num];
};` in `Student.h` and I need to put in `Student.cpp` this code `#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Student.h"` and include in my programm `#include "Student.h"`. Am I right?

Comment: @Heidel: you only need a `Student.cpp` if there are member functions to define in that file. If it's empty, it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of problems with your code, but regarding the one you are asking about it's because the input operator `>>` reads whitespace separated tokens. So if you have a sentence with whitespace (e.g. space, tab, newline) you will only get the first "word".

Use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead.

Comment: Heidel: and mind the difference: `std::getline` not `cin.getline`!

Comment: @quetzalcoatl what's the difference?

Comment: @Heidel Reference for [`std::istream::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline). Read both references and you will see.

Comment: `cin.getline` (actually, istream.getline) works on character arrays. You have to **know** how long your input can be at maximum. With `std::getline` you work with `string` and they allocate the buffer of correct size automatically (simply speaking..)

Comment: Another thing is, as you apparently use cyrylic characters, try to get used to using `wchar_t, wstring, wcin, wcout` instead of `char, string, cin, cout`. The "normal" ones are really only good for plain Latin/ASCII. Of course, "national characters" that fit into your default codepage will work well, but if you try to move and run your program on an OS with different codepage (i.e.: English version of windows), your program may go wild. The `wxxxxxx` version work with Unicode characters and you can roughly assume them to be guaranteed to work regardless of OS language.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborggetline I tried to use `getline (cin, Group[i].name);` and it works for whitespace separated tokens, but I got other problem now - I get `cout` twice at the first time http://i.imgur.com/o3kjVFt.png

Comment: @quetzalcoatl this is very much Windows specific advice. `char` and `wchar_t` say nothing about the encoding of the text, just the size of its code units. In particular, you say `wchar_t` stores "Unicode characters" but Windows uses UTF-16 and not so not every Unicode code point can fit into a single `wchar_t`.

Comment: @wchar_t: this is exactly why I said "Unicode" without saying which kind of, and why "roughly assume" instead of "be absolutely sure" :)

Comment: @wchar_t: are you implying that wchar_t on *nix does not use Unicode? Don't get me wrong, it would be very strange for the cppstandard to enforce any encoding, and surely it does not do that. But I'd quite surprised if `wchar` implementation on Linuxes was not using Unicode

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to try and explain what is causing this error.

Imagine that there is a buffer inside of `cin` which is basically an array of `char`s:

```
 END
  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

At the moment the buffer is empty (as I have tried to show by having END "point" at the first cell). When you say `cin >> name` the first thing `cin` does is check whether there is anything currently in the buffer. If there isn't then it prompts you and copies your input into the buffer:

```
                                 END
                                  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| H | e | l | l | o |   | ! |\n |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Now it copies what is in the buffer (up to a "white space" character) into `name` and move the contents of the buffer down. So now `name == "Hello"` and the buffer looks like this:

```
             END
              |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | ! |\n |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Notice how the buffer is not empty. The next time you do `cin >> name` it does the same check and sees that there is already something in the buffer, **so it doesn't prompt**. This is why your text is printed out without asking you for anything. `cin >> name` will assign `name` the value `"!"` (it will skip the space in front) but the buffer is still not empty; it still has the `\n` character (from when you pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>). `getline` swallows this new line but doesn't include it in the result.

Comment: thank a lot for the explanation, but what should I do? I tried to add `cin.clear()` in my code after `cout` in `cout << "Введите ФИО: ";
  getline (cin, Group[i].name);` but I got `cout` twice http://i.imgur.com/o3kjVFt.png . How to fix it?

Comment: Afer you typed in `5` the buffer looks like `5\n`; when you do `cin >> n` **there is still `\n` in the buffer**. The first `std::getline` will return an empty string. You should do `cin.ignore()` after the `cin >> n` line. You had the right idea with `cin.clear()` but that does something different.

Answer (score 0):

`cin >>` will drop whitespaces. try to use `cin.getline()` instead.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: i don't have criticized nobody. where do you read my critique?